# Django 1.8 reports library

Tags: django, web, report

I need to generate reports in my Django project, I tried django-report-tools but it has incompatiblity with Django > 1.6 versions.

Can somebody recommend  one that works with 1.8?

The reports I need are very simple, pie charts, bar charts and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/reporting/ there are some packages that are `Python 3.x` compatible and are released lately.

I've checked `DJANGO-REPORT-BUILDER` and it supports the latest.

My personal preference is to use `jQuery HighCharts` as Frontend and `Django Rest Framework` to provide `Json` data to the charts.

Answer (score 1):

Just 4 years later :)

Check out this package

https://github.com/ra-systems/django-slick-reporting

It's a reporting engine where you can create grouped by computed reports, time series and crosstab using handful of easy lines of code.
It also comes with Charting out of the box.
Disclaimer: I'm the initial author.

Cheers mate ..